# Different color of rectangles (even/odd row)

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I know how to color the full section (Section Expert - Color - Use Modulo Formula) but I also want to color rectangles in a row different. Well I think best way to explain this is an image:

http://i40.tinypic.com/2jd4wl.png

I made the layout using rectangles (hope they're called so in the english version)

is there any way to solve this? Maybe a possibility to set the background color of a ractangle by a formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that drawing objects, including the box and line, support conditional colors in CR2008. Unfortunately, they also don't support conditional suppression so you can't just stack the objects and selectively suppress them to get the colors you want, either.

Other fields DO support conditional backgrounds, though. So you should be able to do away with the boxes altogether and just use the display fields (whether DB fields, formulas, whatever) to color the report. If you JUST want the colored boxes with no data in it, you can be sneaky and insert a blank text field and conditionally color the background (Right click on field -> "Format Text" -> "Border" tab -> "Background" -> Enter a conditional formula that returns a color). Bam, you've now got yourself a conditionally-colored box/rectangle.